# Can't set "input-channel" on service-activator in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to run some tests with spring integration and I'm running into this strange error.

[image]

It's telling me I can't have an `input-channel` on a service-activator, but I've done this several times before, and in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/service-activator.html) it's used all over the place.

Here's my namespace config.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
xmlns:feed="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed"
xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed/spring-integration-feed.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is problem if your IDE. Looks like it Eclipse.

Try to switch on the Spring Nature for your project.

Or just disagree with it and go ahead with development.

The runtime will tell you properly if you are not right.

On the other hand consider to move away from XML configuration in favor of Java DSL and/or Annotation support.

And yes, try to upgrade to the latest [version](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) - `2.0.0.RC1` is very-very old.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll take a look at the Java DSL.  Also, how did you know what version I was using?